# invert:condition "det==0" is true error with no obvious cause

Tags: 3d, rotation, matrix, godot, transformation

For my project I am turning my `CharacterBody3D` 90 degrees on the x-axis towards a wall.

To achieve this I set `basis.Z` to the `basis.Y`, and then I set `basis.Y` to the `Normal`.

The `X` should stay the same, so I did not do anything with it.
When I tried this I kept getting `invert:condition "det==0" is true` errors. I printed the basis out, and it was not zero, so I checked the scale and the transformation, which were also non-zero.

I looked up online and can't figure out what I'm missing.
Code for current attempt:

```
GD.Print("This is the scale Before Change: " + Scale);
Vector3 DistanceBetweenColliderpoints = Position - ColliderPosition;
GlobalPosition = Position + (DistanceBetweenColliderpoints / 4);
Basis basis = GlobalBasis;
basis.Z = basis.Y;
basis.Y = Normal;
UpDirection = Normal;
GlobalBasis = basis;
GD.Print("This is the scale After Change: " + Scale);
GD.Print("Normal: " + Normal);
```

Code from past attempt:

```
Vector3 DistanceBetweenColliderpoints = Position - ColliderPosition;
GlobalPosition = Position + (DistanceBetweenColliderpoints / 4);
Basis basis = GlobalBasis;
basis.Y = Normal;
basis.Z = Normal.Cross(basis.X);
basis.X=basis.Z.Cross(Normal);
GlobalBasis=basis;
```

I also did this with transform, and it gave me the same error.

Before:
[image: Before]

After:
[image: After]

Video Link:
[Error](https://youtu.be/S-vhQ2I6t8c)

This is what I want to happen:
[image: Picture]

Picture of error:
[image: Error]

Extra info:
[image: GlobalBasis]

Comment: "I printed the basis out, and it was not zero" can you include the printed basid in the body of your question? A matrix determinant can equal zero even if each row/column is non-zero, if two or more of its rows/columns are linearly dependent (i.e. if we can express one row or column as a weighted sum of the others).

Comment: I have included a screenshot of the basis down below and what errors i got,is there anything else i need to do?

Comment: The "After Change" basis has a determinant of -1 in my figuring. Are you sure that's the matrix that's throwing the det == 0 error?